# Can someone explain MVC very simply for me?

Tags: model-view-controller

Can someone explain MVC very simply for me?
I just cant seem to wrap my head around it.

Most tutorials or verbose explanations lose me.

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626803/mvc-model-view-controller-can-it-be-explained-in-simple-terms?rq=1

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To understand MVC in Layman's term, refer to the variation of the [bank analogy](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2009/01/06/another-way-to-think-about-mvc/)

Essentially, MVC is:

- the Model is the part of the code that knows things
- the View is the part of the code that shows the things the Model knows
- the Controller is the part of the code that gets commands from the user and tells the View what to show and the Model what to know.

Answer (score 2):

MVC is a way to separate the core of your application from the graphics parts.
you have a controler, you does all the access and work, and some views, who just display the result and interact with the user, without doing any processing off the data

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Answer (score 2):

It's the separation of data (model), logic (controller) and displaying the results (views). Using MVC has the advantage that the different roles in an application are separated, which makes it more robust. Another advantage is that it's easier to maintain as more developers are used to this way of programming.