# in spring mvc what is the real controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

as i understand MVC pattern as post [MVC question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626803/mvc-model-view-controller-can-it-be-explained-in-simple-terms) 
 -

- the Model is the part of the code that knows things
- the View is the    part of the code that shows the things the Model
  knows
- the Controller    is the part of the code that gets commands from the
  user and tells    the View what to show and the Model what to know.

in spring-mvc we have `DispatcherServlet` which acts as controller gets command from client, also we have developer written controllers which serve commands and resolve the view and prepare Model for that view

in spring-mvc what exactly acts as controller `DispatcherServlet` or developer written controllers

Answer (score 1):

Your `@Controller` annotated classes are your controllers. Think of the DispatcherServlet - as the name tells you - as dispatcher to your controllers.This is the same approach other MVC frameworks also choose (like Struts 2).